# android How to detect Multiple String value inside Edittext

Tags: android

As Stated above. I want to detect all of the similar text inside my `MultiAutoCompleteTextView`.  It only detect the first String Detected in EditText.. What i want is if i have 5 pairs of   it will detect all of them. I want to use this to create a text Validator For example:

```
<script> </script>
<script> </script>
<script> </script>
<script> </script>
<script> </script>
```

If at least one string is not similar.. it will show a toast message plus a number of detected similar text

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Script Tag is Correct" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Here's what i have tried:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 0; i ++ ) {

  String text = txtEditor.getText().toString();
  if (text.contains("<script>") && text.contains("</script>"))
  {
     // If Editor contains the specified String
      Toast.makeText(this, "Script Tag is Correct" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      if (text.contains("var") && text.contains("{") && text.contains("}") && text.contains(";")){
          Toast.makeText(this, "Var Tag is Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }else{
          Toast.makeText(this, "Var Tag is inCorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
 }
 break;
```

Edited:
What i want is if my EditText contains multiple Similar String E.g Below. It will Detect all of the script tag, if the script tag is misspelled or missing a string, it will show a Toast Message.

```
 <script>
    var myObj = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" };
    var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
    window.location = "demo_json.php?x=" + myJSON;
    </script>
    <script> var myObj = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" }; 
     var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj); window.location = "demo_json.php?x=" + myJSON; </script>
```

Comment: explain clearly what actually you want

Comment: updated my Question for clarification

Comment: okay as per my understanding you want to check tag start and end  **_i.e.<script></script>_** from whole string? correct me if i wrong.

Comment: Thats right. it works but it only checks the first Start and end of **i.e. <script> </script> ** from the whole Edittext. so if i have multiple **<script>** tags, it wont detect the next pair.

Comment: okay!! then you can do with array(Y),what you have to a do add in to array list when your _if (text.contains("<script>") && text.contains("</script>"))_ this condition TRUE.

Comment: can you help me how can i achieve that?

Comment: check it answer

Answer (score 0):

**//Declare arrayList**

ArrayList scriptStartTag = new ArrayList();

ArrayList scriptEndTag = new ArrayList();

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= 0; i ++ ) {

              String text = txtEditor.getText().toString();
              if (text.contains("<script>"))
              {

                  // If Editor contains the specified String
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Script Tag is Correct" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  //add in to start arrayList
                  scriptCount.add("startTagFound");
                  if (text.contains("<script>")){
                  //add in to end arrayList
                  scriptEndTag.add("endTagFound")
                  }



                  if (text.contains("var") && text.contains("{") && text.contains("}") && text.contains(";"))

                  {

                      Toast.makeText(this, "Var Tag is Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
                  else

                  {

                      Toast.makeText(this, "Var Tag is inCorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
             }
             }
```

**//Checking  pairs if count 5 then do what you want**

```
 if (scriptStartTag.size() == 5 && scriptEndTag.size() == 5) {
            if (scriptStartTag.size() == scriptEndTag.size()) {
                //do what you want 
            } else {
                //your error msg 
            }
        } else {
            //your error msg 
        }
```

Comment: it is still the same as my code before. if i have multiple pairs of **<script>** tags it wont detect the next pair. I need this to make a syntax validator for edittext. for example if one of the **<script> ** tags is mispelled or missing something it will show a toast message

Comment: so you need to  check 2 individual condition one for <simple> this tag and another for </script> tag and also manage two arrayList at same time and make sure both arrayList size will same after forLoop.

Comment: Thats right.. E.g. if i have 3 pairs of **<script> and </script>** tags . and the third pair is tag is mispelled or missing a letter like **<script or </scrip ** it will show a toast showing Tags are incorrect.

Comment: okay update your trial code ill check and let me inform you for same.

Answer (score 0):

I found this code works for me. it finds all of the `<script> </script>` Tag from the whole edittext. Is it possible to have a for loop inside a loop? and also get the line number based from the index i get.

```
String text2 = txtEditor.getText().toString();
                    String word = "<script>";
                    String word2 = "</script>";
                    if (text2.contains(word) && text2.contains(word2)) {



                        //Start 1st if
                        for (int i = -1; (i = text2.indexOf(word, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "<Script> Tag is Correct " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                        for (int i = -1; (i = text2.indexOf(word2, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "</Script> Tag is Correct " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                        }


                    }

                        else
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(this, "Script Tag is inCorrect" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
```